# MVP pattern application in Delphi XE5 targeting Android and Windows platform

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am starting a new project on Delphi XE5 and it is based on MVP patter.

My views are totally dumb.

In this case I can create views targeting Android and others windows (FMX or VCL).

This is a business application, so if I have the same look and controls on Android it is not a problem at all.

I am new to XE5 and targeting android. I am new to FMX. I work with VCL since Delphi 1.

I have not found resources about sharing the same code between platforms.

My questions:

1) is it possible to share the same code between these platforms? (the M-P pattern part)
2) is it possible to have the same FMX form on both? Android Tablet will have the same look and feel of the windows in this case.

I am a newbie on these and the searches I made do not addressed these questions, if there are links to resources, please share.

Comment: You don't want the same form on desktop and mobile. Unless your target mobile devices have xga monitors and mice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have 2 options: mostly it will be used as a windows replacement solution, so xga tablets with mouse and keyboard. However the interface will be modeled to be more friendly for touchscreen. No small monitors.

Comment: Then you might well be fine to share forms.

Comment: Also have a look into frames. You can share frames between platforms and maybe combine them in forms in different ways depending on the screen size and format. Even a table screen, when rotated, must be handled someway. Frames are a good way to share pieces of views among different forms and layouts.

Comment: In the `DSharp` project there is an MVVM branch that currently works on Windows with VCL and FMX. We're working on getting a few Mac OS X glitches done, then concentrate on getting it to work in the mobile platforms (the multi-cast events are the limiting factor right now). Look for the Feature/Caliburn branch. We can use some help now that Spring4D finally got released. https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/83368a5cba57d1aa88af3a9e3ea45aa33b692ea4/?at=feature%2FCaliburn