# Best way to implement MVVM bindings (View <-> ViewModel) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mvvm, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

For a multi-platform application using native components, the standard Delphi approach is no longer sufficient. So far our structure had only to parts: GUI (Forms) and Business logic. We now need to split the "Forms" part into two, which in a MVVM context would be `View` and `ViewModel`.

The bindings between View and ViewModel can be handled in different ways:

- LiveBindings in Delphi
- [DSharp (Delphi Sorcery)](https://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/)
- [Delphi Spring (Spring4D)](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/)

There might be more. I know this is a religious question to some, but I still hope it is possible to get objective answers:

If you are using a solution in your Firemonkey application that is suitable for multi-platform development on a long term perspective: What considerations was behind the decision you made?

Comment: Best way is to create some prototypes for each and evaluate them :/

Comment: Why is this put on hold? I specifically ask for objective answers. Several people must have been through an evaluation process similar to mine and come to conclusions that can be useful for the community.

Comment: Also you asked for an objective answer - this is philosophy and each objective answer is based on the opinion of the poster

Comment: And if you can point to other survey questions, we'll be glad to close vote them too.  They're specifically discouraged here, as they are better suited to forums rather than our question/answer format.  You could venture into [chat] and see if there's a popular delphi room where you can ask for opinions...  For more info, search for "opinion based questions" on [meta].

Comment: To ask what solution you think is the best is not objective, but to tell the pros and cons you have found is objective enough to be useful for the community. If I get the reason for the opinion then I can decide if that reason is good enough for me and I can make my own decision. However, I agree that this question does not fit very well with the SO approach of giving final answers.

Comment: I've gone through it. `DSharp` is currently the best, though not yet finished. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142369/mvp-pattern-application-in-delphi-xe5-targeting-android-and-windows-platform), [this German post](http://www.delphipraxis.net/1252843-post48.html), and my [presentation materials from the BE-Delphi conference](https://github.com/jpluimers/Conferences/commit/5899b0fe213e3edf096a2f0aade9f09856cb19e9).

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Great slides you have there, they exactly describe the situation.